# what is the advantage of using PUT over POST

Tags: php, rest

I creating a REST application with php. I would like to know is there
any advantage of using PUT method orver POST for updating ?

Also i can use GET for deleting why should i use `DELETE` method ?

This application will be used by browser and mobile apps

Answer (score 1):

If you develop your web application only for browser, you should go with post and get.

But e.g. REST-APIs should/could make use of the put and delete methods. So you could better define what action you want to execute on special resources. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

taken from [what's the advantage of using put and delete as opposed to just get and post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080392/whats-the-advantage-of-using-put-and-delete-as-opposed-to-just-get-and-post)